# How to inner join two tables?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, better-sqlite3

To extend a column (col_F) into the final output (File3) by comparing File 1 and File2.

Col_A has possessed a relationship between File1 and File2. I have to use this relationship and omit values in the col_F into File3.

For an example:

```
File1
col_A       col_F                          
 A1      F1
 A2      F2
 A5      F5
 AZ      FZ
 AX      FX
 A#      F#
 A2      F2


File2  
col_A  col_B      col_C   col_D
  A1    B        C       D
  A2    B        C       D
  A5    B        C       D
  AZ    B        C       D
  AX    B        C       D
  A#    B        C       D
  A2    B        C       D


File3_Final output (Query result) 
col_A  col_B    col_C   col_D   col_F
A1      B        C        D      F1
A2      B        C        D      F2
A5      B        C        D      F5
A       B        C        D      FZ
AX      B        C        D      FX
A#      B        C        D      F#
A2      B        C        D      F2


NOTE: All the Tables are saved in .csv format
```

Comment: What have you tried? Why is this tagged with Perl? What does this have to do with MySQL or MongoDB?

Comment: You say CSV, but you say SQL. Which is it?

Comment: @ikegami I have two CSV files (file1 and file1) /MySQL (we can consider this CSV file as tables (Table1 and Table2). If can help me with python code, will be great.

Comment: @Grinnz Here, I got a bit confused, I am aware that I can solve this with My SQL  with following scripts

Comment: I think MongoDB tag should be removed from this question and I am going to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you want solutions in Python, MySQL or MongoDB. But you've tagged the question with "perl". So here's a Perl solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %file1 = get_file1();

open my $fh2, '<', 'File2' or die "File 2: $!\n";

chomp(my $header = <$fh2>);
print "$header\tcol_F\n";

while (<$fh2>) {
  chomp;
  my $colA = (split ' ')[0];
  print "$_\t$file1{$colA}\n";
}

sub get_file1 {
  my %hash;

  open my $fh1, '<', 'File1' or die "File 1: $!\n";

  <$fh1>; # skip headers
  while (<$fh1>) {
    chomp;
    my ($key, $val) = split ' ';
    $hash{$key} = $val;
  }

  return %hash;
}
```

Comment: Getting following error, how can I solve it?     Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./complier line 16, <$fh2> line 2.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ./complier line 16,

Comment: @Jay: That's not an error, it's a warning. It means that File2 contains a value for col_A that doesn't appear in File1. It's up to you how you deal with that situation.

Comment: @Jay: That seems like a pretty obvious error to work out :-) The current code assumes that both input files are in the current directory when you run the program. If that's not the case, then you'll need to adjust the paths in the two `open()` calls.

Comment: I will try @Dave